# Angular 2 : Radio Button active using value in ngModel

Tags: angular, radio-button

the radio button should be checked according to the value i get in the ngModel, the value that will get on ngModel will be 1 or 0

```
 <div class="col-md-6" id="radio-demo">
               <input type="radio" name="in_stock"   id="first-choice"  [(ngModel)]="fifthSector.in_stock"   />
           <label for="first-choice">Yes</label>

           <input type="radio" name="in_stock" id="second-choice"   [(ngModel)]="fifthSector.in_stock"   />
           <label for="second-choice">No</label>
             </div>
```

[image]

now i am getting both radio buttons not checked, how it can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [value] directive. Try this:

```
<input name="options" type="radio" [value]="0"  [(ngModel)]="fifthSector.in_stock">Yes<br/>

<input name="options" type="radio" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="fifthSector.in_stock" >No<br/>

Value:
{{fifthSector.in_stock}}
```

Stackblizt example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhqd46